# Difference Between Nullify and Cascade, Deny In Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I  am Developing Core Data Based Application

can anyone explain Difference Between Nullify and Cascade, Deny In Core Data

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: The "Relationship Delete Rules" are explained in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html. Which part is unclear to you?

Comment: A related to B, If A deleted then what will happen in B in "nullify"

Comment: *"Nullify: Remove the relationship between the objects but do not delete either object."* – If A is deleted then the (inverse) relationship from the B object to A is set to nil.

Answer (score 2):

A relationship's delete rule specifies what should happen if an attempt is made to delete the source object. Note the phrasing if an attempt is made. If a relationship's delete rule is set to Deny, it is possible that the source object will not be deleted. Consider again a department's employees relationship, and the effect of the different delete rules.

Deny
If there is at least one object at the relationship destination (employees), do not delete the source object (department).

For example, if you want to remove a department, you must ensure that all the employees in that department are first transferred elsewhere (or fired!); otherwise, the department cannot be deleted.

Nullify
Remove the relationship between the objects but do not delete either object.

This only makes sense if the department relationship for an employee is optional, or if you ensure that you set a new department for each of the employees before the next save operation.

Cascade
Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship when you delete the source.

For example, if you delete a department, fire all the employees in that department at the same time.

No Action
Do nothing to the object at the destination of the relationship.